# In Spark's Dataset<T>::map() function, can I mutate the object?

Tags: java, apache-spark, immutability

Spark's `DataFrame`, or `Dataset<Row>`, assumes that `Row` is immutable. I heard that the immutability is the foundation of failure tolerance, concurrency and optimizations.

But for a `Dataset` of a custom class `A`, can I mutate the object in `Dataset<A>::map()` function?

Example code:

```java
@Data
public class A {
    private String x;
}

...

Dataset<A> ds = ...

ds.map((MapFunction<A, A>) row -> {
    row.setX("another value");
    return row;
}, Encoders.bean(A.class));
```

Although the mutation works, but I am not sure if it is always safe or recommended to do so.